# Was my fireplace insert correctly installed?

Tags: outdoor, fireplace, brick

I just had an outdoor fireplace put in with a gas insert. I hate that the metal sides of the insert are clearly visible. I had my contractor paint them white in the hopes that it would blend in with the white brick surround. My questions are -

Does this look like it was properly installed? Is it normal for the metal sides to be visible? I did not expect to see any metal, just brick that ran into the surround on the sides and the lava rock on the bottom.

If this does look like it was properly installed, any ideas on how to cover the metal?Ideally with brick? My contractor said we cannot add brick because it won't adhere to the metal but can we add a different material to the metal to then apply brick onto?

Any advice appreciated! This was an expensive project and it's upsetting that I am not happy with the final appearance.

[image]

Comment: What did your contract specify with the contractor? Have you made final payment? Have you looked at the installation instructions for the insert? Maybe this is the way it's supposed to be installed. If you'll at least get us the brand/model maybe someone will do you the courtesy of looking up the instructions to see if this was installed properly.

Comment: Did you not look at the fireplace when selecting it ?  Have you asked the manufacturer for help?

Comment: Most fireplaces have a screen or glass; that frame is probably intended for mounting such.

Comment: Presumably the slots in the metal are to hang a grill or a glass front on this fireplace. Either that or some trim connects through thos slots. This does look unfinished, incomplete. Usually those are black or architectural bronze. Painting the metal surround black would make it fade into the background better than white. Where does it get its combustion air? Does it distribute warmed air into the surroundings from vents?

Comment: Also, paint, unless specifically "high temperature paint" will likely bake off pretty quickly, even under the relatively cool temps of a gas insert.

Answer (score 3):

While brick wont stick to metal, you could easily let the tiles or brick veneer hang over the edge.  That will hide it.

On the other hand, both our gas fireplaces (from different manufacturers) have metal surrounds such as this and a baffle to grab more heat from it and a fan to distribute it.

And the slots on the metal frame suggest that it is missing something.

[image]